# How to pass a dynamic value in angular2-counto

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using the following library:

- https://github.com/izupet/angular2-counto

I'm getting an error when I pass a dynamic value.

So in my component `app.component.html`:

If I use interpolation:

```
<div counto [step]="30" [countTo]="'{{value}}'" [countFrom]="0 [duration]="4" (countoChange)="counto = $event" (countoEnd)="onCountoEnd()">{{counto | currency:'EUR':true:'1.2-2'}}</div>
```

I get an error related with the double braces syntax:

```
[countTo]="'{{value}}'"
```

Otherwise, without them it works:

```
 [countTo]="10"
```

---

Here for [countTo] attribute passing the value from component.

For app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

  value=10;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct sintax is:

**[countTo]="value"**

without **{{}}** and without **single quotes**

This is because, countTo Input from library extects a number.

Comment: I have tried with interpolation [countTo]="{{value}}" not working getting `error: compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{value}}] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@26:26 ("
  </div>`

Comment: You dont need interpolation here, because the component input expect a number. If you have a var named value on the component.ts, you can use this var like [countTo]="value" without singles quotes and without interpolation.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as accepted if the answer really helped you. It will help other people with the same problem that you had. You only have to click the tick under the answer score.

Answer (score 1):

In angular, the use of `[]` is for when the value is a binding expression (your case).

So, for example, an input:

```
<input value="data"> // value is `data`, a string
<input [value]="data"> // value is a property of the current component's class called `data`, can be an object, array, number, string, etc.
```

That's why you need to use just the name of the property in order to pass it as value of a tag's attribute surrounded by `[]`.

Therefore, using `[countTo]="value"` will work just fine if the `value` property in your class is defined and accepted by the library that you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove quotes from binding like this:

`[countTo]="{{value}}"`

or bind to change function like this:

`(countoChange)="handleCountChange($event)"`

and then in Component code:

`handleCountChange(data) {
 return this.value; // or whatever you like 
}`

Comment: it is working when given like this [countTo]="value"